# when i downloading a zip file Every time name is changing i write the following code for download the zip file

Tags: javascript

When I downloading a zip file Every time name is changing 
I write the following code for download the zip file.

```
var url = Mypath1 + "DownloadFiles/DeliveryOrders.zip";               
window.open(url, '_self', 'Download', false);
```

[image]

Comment: when i firsttime its name is DeliveryOrders ,second time DeliveryOrders(2) ,DeliveryOrders(3)  like this happen .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Windows behavior that OP does not understand

Comment: So what're you expecting instead? When it tries to write file with given file name, it will see there is already another file with same name, so it will add a number to create a new file name.

Answer (score 2):

It's because windows don't overwrite your files and appends `(##)` to the end of your file names.

Comment: thanks for reply .what i can do i  for overwrite and not to append the (##)

Comment: You can't - that would be a serious security issue, not to mention a usability nigthmare. It's up to the browser to do this (and up to the human using it to optionally override); in-page JavaScript has no power over it.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemMohammad Change browser settings to always ask for download location, when poped-out to select location just select old file and confirm overwrite for that file.

Comment: (Technically, it's the *browser* that's responsible for this behavior, not the OS; although this bog-standard behavior did originate with Internet Explorer sometime around version 4; so it was sort-of OS-integrated then)

Answer (score 1):

When your browser is determining what file name to use to save the HTTP resource to:

- it is looking at the URL
- using that to select its first choice
- looking in your downloads folder and seeing that a file of that name already exists
- adding a number so that it doesn't overwrite the file

This is normal behaviour.

You can't change that browser behaviour.